# Reading Socket InputStream in a loop when writing byte arrays

Tags: java, sockets

This is what you usually do when sending **text** data

```
// Receiver code
while (mRun && (response = in.readLine()) != null && socket.isConnected()) {
    // Do stuff                 
}

// Sender code
printWriter.println(mMessage);
printWriter.flush();
```

but when working with `DataOutputStream#write(byte[])` to send `byte[]`, how do you write a `while` loop to receive sent data.

All I have found is this, but it doesn't loop, so I'm guessing this will just run on the first sent message:

```
int length = in.readInt();
byte[] data = new byte[length];
in.readFully(data);
```

How can I achieve this?

**PS:** yep, I'm new to socket programming.

**EDIT:** I'm sending a byte array each 3 to 5 seconds. This is what I've got so far.

```
// In the client side, in order to send byte[]. This is executed each 3 seconds.
if(out != null) {
    try {
        out.writeInt(encrypted.length);
        out.write(encrypted);
        out.writeInt(0);
        out.flush();
        return true;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    }
}


 // In the serverside, in order to receive byte[] sent from client (also executed 3 to 5 seconds due to bytes being sent at said rate.  "client" being the Socket instance.
while(true && client.isConnected()) {

    byte[] data = null;

    while(true) {
        int length = in.readInt();
        if(length == 0)
            break;

        data = new byte[length];
        in.readFully(data);
    }

    if(data != null) {
        String response = new String(data);

        if(listener != null) {
            listener.onMessageReceived(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you even tried the code? why wont it work? your question isnt very clear

Comment: cause I don't know what expression to do with the while loop

Comment: i still dont understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to handle a stream of messages, sounds like what you're missing is a way of specifying (in the stream) how big your messages are (or where they end).

I suggest you just write a prefix before each message, specifying the length:

```
output.writeInt(data.length);
output.write(data);
```

Then when reading:

```
while (true)
{
    int length = input.readInt();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    input.readFully(buffer, 0, length);
    // Process buffer
}
```

You'll *also* need to work out a way of detecting the end of input. `DataInputStream` doesn't have a clean way of detecting that as far as I can tell. There are various options - the simplest may well be to write out a message of length 0, and break out of the loop if you read a length of 0.

Comment: I'm guessing when you do `bufferedReader.readLine()` it keeps waiting for a break line. So what you are saying is that I should loop until a character sequence is met?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco: No, I didn't say that at all - if you're writing a byte array, there's no such thing as a character sequence. You *could* use a byte sequence instead, but usually it's better to just use a length prefix instead.

Comment: I see. Where should I put the `if` statement to break the loop when the length is 0? after `readFully()`?

Comment: Ok, now then, in the sending part, I'd put `output.writeInt(0)` after `output.write(byte[])` right?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco: Well you'd put it outside whatever loop you've got - basically when you've sent *all* the messages. (If you're only sending a single message, you don't need any of this...)

Comment: I updated my question, with what I've got yet. Could you check it out please?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco: You're only using the *final* message here - your `onMessageReceived` call should be *inside* the loop. Also, if this is encrypted data, then `new String(data)` is almost certainly *not* what you want.

Comment: I see, but besides the callback and the string init, does the send-receive byte operation needs something else? I'm getting an exception due to end of file

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco: Well you *also* appear to have `writeInt(0)` in your loop in the client - as I said, you should only be calling that when the client is "done" and the server should stop listening. And you've got *two* `while` loops in the server - why?

Comment: As I said I don't understand well the concept of waiting for input in the serverside. I put 2 whiles, first to keep running as long as the socket is openned, and the second one to keep reading the inputstream until it's done. the latter I dont know if it's ok because of what i said above. Could you write how should the loop go please?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco: No, it's not okay - you only need *one* `while` loop, to keep going as long as the client isn't trying to send you data. The client is going to indicate that it's done by sending a 0-length message. You just need a *single* loop of "Read message length, read message data, process message" - quitting the loop if the length is 0.